# Understanding a curve system on the boundary of Teichmuller space

Tags: algebraic-curves, riemann-surfaces, teichmueller-theory

I am reading the paper:

https://arxiv.org/pdf/1511.07635.pdf

and I try to understand the behavior on the boundary. I have some problems understanding this definition.

On page 26, the authors give a definition of a curve system (**Definition 4.6**)

> Let $\Sigma_{g,n}$ be a Riemann surface of genus $g$ with $n$ marked
> points $Q=\{q_1,\ldots,q_n\}$. a **curve system** $c=\{c_i\}_{i\in I}$
> in $\Sigma_{g,n}$ is a disjoint collection of simple closed curves
> $c_i$ on $\Sigma_{g,n}\setminus Q$ such that none of which is isotopic
> to any other, to a point or to a cylinder in $\Sigma_{g,n}\setminus Q$.

> To a curve system $c$ we can associate the subset $B_c\subset T_{g,n}$
> of the boundary of the Teichmuller space of stable curves genus $g$ with $n$
> marked points consisting of homotopically marked stable curves
> topologically equivalent to a collapse $\Sigma_g\to \Sigma/c$ obtained
> by identifying each curve in $c$ to a point.

My questions are:

1. What does a curve isotopic to a cylinder mean?
2. How are the elements of $B_c$?

I will appreciate any comments. Thanks in advance.

**Edit**

A **stable curve** $C$ is a complex connected curve with $n$ marked points such that its singularities are nodes and do not coincide with any of the marked points and the closure of each component of $C^*=C\setminus Sing(C)$ has a group of automorphisms that fix the marked points and the boundary points is finite.

Comment: Your second question peters off into an incomplete and mis-spelled sentence. Moreover the definition of $B_c$ requires significant pre-requisites, so without knowing more clearly where your misunderstanding lies, that second question is difficult to answer. For example, do you understand the concept of "stable curves"? If not, I will suggest that you delve into that concept, and then to formulate a proper question in another post --- in line with our policy to ask [one question per post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#33671).

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment.

Answer (score 1):

I will answer your first question --- and let me also suggest that for a fuller answer you should consult the standard texts on this theory: the books of [Farb and Margalit](https://press.princeton.edu/books/hardcover/9780691147949/a-primer-on-mapping-class-groups-pms-49); and of [Fathi, Laudenback, Poenaru et. al.](https://press.princeton.edu/books/paperback/9780691147352/thurstons-work-on-surfaces-mn-48).

Regarding your question about cylinders, it looks like there is a mistake in the wording: a few words are missing. The correct wording (similar to a later usage of the term *cylinder* in the paper) should be:

> ... none of which is isotopic to any other, to a point, or to a *curve in a cylinder representing one of the ends of $\Sigma_{g,n} \setminus Q$*.